# http:inbound-endpoint host 0.0.0.0 rebind to local ip in pattern:web-service-proxy does not work

Tags: web-services, proxy, mule

**Mule Version: 3.4.0 CE**

I'm using pattern:web-service-proxy and my inbound-endpoint is set to 0.0.0.0, like this:

**config file contains:**
http.host=0.0.0.0
http.port=8080

**flow**

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="adm-core-group-ws-proxy">
    <http:inbound-endpoint   host="${http.host}" port="${http.port}" path="adm/group/GroupService" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint host="${visto.host}" port="${visto.port}" path="visto-system-service/GroupService" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

**the result of wsdl location**

```
<wsdl:service name="GroupService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:GroupServiceSoapBinding" name="GroupServicePortTypeImplPort">
  <soap:address location="http://0.0.0.0:8080/adm/group/GroupService"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

If you notice, the host is not replaced with the machine ip, like in other cases.

Is that a known error?

Maybe I can "fixed" it by using the machine host name instead, but is that a good way to solve it? And is it going to work?

Thank you!

Comment: wsdl: http://pastebin.com/sPuijcK7
xsd adm: http://pastebin.com/PyVC54tQ
xsd core:http://pastebin.com/6NRSpEqR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the fact the remote WSDL contains a bad address:

```
<soap:address location="http://system/adm/service/group/v1_0_0/GroupService.GroupServicePortType" />
```

Instead of `system` it should be the value of `${visto.host}`, that way the WSProxy could replace it with the host value from the inbound HTTP request that hits the `http:inbound-endpoint`.

Can this remote WSDL be fixed? If not, you'll have to download it, fix it by hand then refer to it in the `pattern:web-service-proxy` as a file-based WSDL.

Comment: just so you know I left it fixed. Thanks!!